# Why has my Android app stopped unexpectedly?

Tags: android

I am new to Android programing and the following program is my first Android app
My `.java` file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    private OnClickListener btn_click = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            btn.setText("Hi there!");

        }
    };
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        btn.setOnClickListener(btn_click);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }    
}
```

My `.XML` file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want once I tap button `My Button` it's text changes to "Hi there!". But when my app is being to run in emulator, It breaks and a message pops up:
**The Application testapp_1(process com.example.testapp_1) has stoped unexpectedly**

What is my mistakes? and how I can fix them?

Comment: `Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);` You will also need to move this into a method.  All Java executable code must exist inside a method.  Probably put it in `onCreate` depending on what visibility you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your initialization after `setContentView`.

```
Button btn;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn); // initalize button after setContentView
    btn.setOnClickListener(btn_click);
}
```

You need to set the content to the activity first and then initialize your views. You initialized outside `onCreate`. You will get `NullPointerException`. You can `findViewById` of the current view hierarchy set to the activity.

Comment: Where is this `stack trace`? Note that I use emulator in eclipse

Comment: You can get the stack trace from `logcat`

Comment: @ABFORCE In Eclipse goto windows --> open perspective--> ddms --> logcat.